# Mapbox extrusions show in Android but not iOS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I have a Mapbox map style created in Studio to which I have added extrusion layers. These appear in my app on Android, but not in iOS. I did not change anything in the app to make them appear. I'm using the Mapbox iOS framework 4.9 - as far as I can tell extrusions were supported before that version. The two versions are using the same map style.

Any ideas what I'm not doing?

This is the Android version:

[image: Android screenshot]

And this is what the same map looks like on iOS.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating the SDK to 5.2.0 and migrating the map to a later version in Mapbox Studio made the extrusions appear on iOS. I have no idea which of those changes was important.